# JQuery Append Data at end of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="myTable0" name="myTable0">
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="myTable1" name="myTable1">
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need some JQuery that will attempt to append new html to the end of a table and do it on the enter key, it will also select the correct table to append it to as there are numerous tables.

Here is my code that doesn't work but attempts to do this:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
$("#newComment" + i).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        var $test= $('<tr><td>content here</td></tr>');
        $('#myTable '+ i + ' > tbody:last').append($test);
    }
}
```

The line that is throwing me problems is the Jquery select which follows:

```
$('#myTable '+ i + ' > tbody:last').append($newdiv1);
```

Comment: what is the content of $newdiv1? Is it by any chance something other than a tr?

Comment: It looks like $newdiv1 is undefined from the code you've shared above. Perhaps you ment to write $test?

Comment: @Martin correct sorry about that guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#myTable' + i + ' > tbody:last').append($newdiv1);
```

The space `$('#myTable '` is the problem..

You are having space between #myTable and 0..

You need `#myTable0` while you were having `#myTable 0`

Comment: and also $newdiv1 does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yup this is very simple
just do like this

```
$('#myTable'+ i).find('tr:last').append($test);
```

And thats done.

Comment: This had a nasty effect, it inserted my rows just before the last closing TR tag of the last row, instead of AFTER the closing TR tag. Rajat's solution works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo? I think you mean $test instead if $newdiv1 in a problematic line.

I can see you have only one `<tbody>` tag so the ':last' selector is not necessary. I think that

```
$('#myTable' + i + ' tbody').append($test);
```

will be fine.

Edit: Yup, as Rajat Singhal said remove sapce in selector after #myTable.