# Javascript/PHP Fetching contents of array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have an array of data in PHP, being displayed in 25 table cells on a webpage. I also have a javascript function that determines when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page. My question is, what are the steps to fetching another 25 elements or so from the PHP array and displaying 25 more?

I am aware that Javascript is a client side language whereas PHP is a server side language, but I'm not sure how that affects me...Thanks

Best...SL

Comment: Show us the array and the code.

Comment: Here is my javascript to reach the bottom:
<script language=Javascript>
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
   alert(myarray[0]);
  }
 });
</script>

Comment: How much of the dataset is being loaded into the php array, if all of it is, load it into a javascript array and use a count variable. Then once your function detects the bottom of the page append another 25 records to the table using the count until 25 is reached. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339202/jquery-append-data-at-end-of-table

Comment: I'm getting it there by doing this in PHP, where $cities is my array:

echo '<script>var myarray = '.json_encode($cities).';</script>';

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's difficult, but I'll take a stab at it:

Use jQuery to hit the PHP once the user has scrolled to the bottom. Parse the data returned from the PHP and refresh your table.